# Auth0 plugin Nativescript error - There was an error processing the sign in

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, nativescript, auth0

I'm trying to set up Auth0 plugin in my Nativescript app. So far I've installed the plugin (https://github.com/sitefinitysteve/nativescript-auth0) and I get the Log-in screen but whenever i enter my credentials i get the error "there was an error processing the sign in."

The callback URL is set according to the plugin tutorial, and i think everything else is in order.

Bellow is the screenshot of the error:

[image: this is the error]

I'm fairly new to Nativescript and would like to hear if anyone's had a take on this subject, i haven't been able to figure it out. Also, a sample of code would be of great help if somebody can share. Thanks!

P.S. I didn't leave any code out here because i didn't know what could be relevant, i deem this to be a problem with the plugin itself.

Comment: In your Auth0 dashboard go to "Logs" and you should be able to see (and post) more detailed error log.

Comment: Nah, i thought so too, someone also proposed it on some site, but my logs are empty. I presume it's because the request never makes it to Auth0?

Comment: If you find this to be a problem specific to a plugin, it might be best to create an issue in that plugin's repository.

Comment: I probably will. Though, i haven't been able to find much info about my problem anywhere so i though other programmers who used Auth0 managed to do it correctly whilst i'm doing something wrong. When i said "problem with the plugin itself" i meant something to do with the implementation/configuration of the plugin, not that it's bugged.